# How to install 32-bit deb package on 64-bit ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, apt, dependencies, multiarch

I have Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit installed and I have to install 32-bit deb package on it. It depends on other 32 bit libraries. I overcome this with getlibs:

```
sudo getlibs -i ./hp-netconnect_1.2-12_i386.deb
```

Package is installed successfully and I can use it, but now I can't install anything with apt-get:

```
ytaras@bueno:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install bison-doc 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 hp-netconnect:i386 : Depends: openssl:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: procps:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: zenity:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: sun-java6-jre:i386 but it is not installable or
                               sun-java5-jre:i386 but it is not installable
                      Recommends: sun-java6-plugin:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I run 'apt-get -f install', it just removes hp-netconnect package. Now I have to uninstall this package with 'apt-get -f install' every time I want to install something and reinstall it later.

Comment: How about `dpkg -i --force-architecture hp-netconnect_1.2-12_i386.deb`?

Comment: It works, but later on apt-get shows same output about unmet dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With multiarch, you don't need `getlibs`, the dependencies should "just-work".
However, the problem here is that `openssl`, `procps`, `zenity`, and Java haven't been marked as `MultiArch: foreign` yet. Meaning that the amd64 versions will probably work for this script, but `dpkg` can't see that.

I'm afraid, your best way around this is probably to edit that `.deb`, and remove the problematic dependencies. Somebody [wrote a script](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=636724) to help with that.

Answer (score 5):

You can install a 32 bit package on ubuntu use dpkg with the flag --ignore-depends. If you do that dependencies of this package should be ignored.

So I would try:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-architecture --ignore-depends hp-netconnect_1.2-12_i386.deb
```

Alternatively you can as well ignore missing dependencies with apt by attach --ignore-missing flag.

Comment: --ignore-missing works, but only for install, I can't, for example, remove package. If I uninstall currently installed package and install it with line you gave, it still shows same output in apt-get.